# Add ProgressBar programmatically winRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have created metro apps and I have already created view base for my view like this

```
public class ViewBase : Page,IView
    {
        public object Parameter { get; private set; }
        private ProgressBar _progressRing;

        public ViewBase()
        {
            Parameter = null;
            _progressRing = new ProgressBar
            {
                IsIndeterminate = true,
                Height = 25,
                Width = 100,
                FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                Margin = new Thickness(0,12,0,0)
            };
        }

        public ViewBase(object parameter)
        {
            Parameter = parameter;
            _progressRing = new ProgressBar
            {
                IsIndeterminate = true,
                Height = 25,
                Width = 100,
                FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue),
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                Margin = new Thickness(0, 12, 0, 0)
            };
        }

        #region Properties

        public virtual string Title
        {
            get { return ""; }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IView

        public async void DisplayMessage(MessageHandler handler)
        {
            await MessageBoxHelper.ShowAsync(handler);
        }


        public void SetAsBusy()
        {
            _progressRing.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Frame.IsEnabled = false;
        }

        public void SetAsIdle()
        {
            _progressRing.Visibility=Visibility.Collapsed;
            Frame.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

So now what I need is whenever my view call `SetAsBusy()` I need to show my `progressBar`. But it seems I can not add it. `Frame.AddChild()` is not exist for WinRT API. So how do I do that? I can add progressbar manually in all my view but it will get too much

Comment: You can add it as a Child to some of your controls (like Grid or StackPanel)

Comment: that means I need to add it in all of my view? I need to do it in my view base so I don't recreate all my ProgressBar

Answer (score 0):

*"that means I need to add it in all of my view? I need to do it in my view base so I don't recreate all my ProgressBar"*

Well by default yes. What you could do is to have a "shell" page around your regular frame, and than set your navigation to interact with that inner frame.

[image: Basic setup you probably want]

Comment: How do I can create like that in my ViewBase? I already had that idea but can not find the implementation...